# How can I log all queries in a MongoDB sharded environment?

Tags: mongodb

To be compliant with new regulations, I need to log all queries sent to the database with the username of the originator.
In a non sharded environment, I just had to set the profiling level to 2 with the command db.setProfilingLevel(2). I can do the same on each node of my cluster but then I don't know how to access the system.profile collections.

Is there a way to log all queries received by the mongos directly in the log file? I see there are some auditing parameters available in the enterprise edition, is there a way to do something similar with the community edition?

The ideal logs would contain:

- db/collection
- authenticated user
- timestamp
- query

Comment: [Quoting the documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/#database-profiling-and-sharding): *You cannot enable profiling on a mongos instance. To enable profiling in a sharded cluster, you must enable profiling for each mongod instance in the cluster.*. So do that and simply access the data from each node. Nothing stopping you doing that. Or sit and wait for https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1957

Comment: This really should be asked on [dba,stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com) which is for questions and answers relating to database administration and configuration. StackOverflow is for :"programming" based questions, of which this is not. Please move your post to the appropriate site instead of posting here.

Comment: I cannot move the question to dba.stackexchange.com, I don't have enough reputation. You can do it if you do.

Comment: That is completely untrue. Anyone can delete their own post and anyone can post on the site. In fact, you "gain" 100 reputation purely by creating a linked account on another stackexchange site. Which should be reason enough to do it alone.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the profiling function log every query to the log, by setting the [threshold for 'slow' operations](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/#specify-the-threshold-for-slow-operations) to zero:

```js
db.setProfilingLevel(0, 0);
```

This does not enable the full [profiler](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/), but does make it log a few pieces of data about every query, writing it to the server log, like this:

> 2017-06-15T09:15:58.809+0000 I COMMAND  [conn305112] query mydatabasename.mycollectionname planSummary: COLLSCAN ntoreturn:1000 ntoskip:0 nscanned:0 nscannedObjects:6 keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:0 nreturned:6 reslen:4863 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 2 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 1 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 1 } } } 1ms

This does not really give you exactly the information you asked for, but if you want that then I think you will have to pay for MongoDB Enterprise to get the [auditing functionality](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/auditing/).

Comment: I really need the user who did each action to be compliant, I'll check the enterprise version or the percona version.